Accessing environment variables from Go for Serverless Api
I have a go API setup using Serverless. In my root directory I have main.go and .env, as well as a config folder which contains config.go. I'm having issues as my attempts to access the endpoint throws a runtime error due to it being unable to access the environment variables once deployed (works fine locally).
When I deploy to AWS, and test out the endpoint I get: Failed to load env file: open ./.env: no such file or directory. How do I fix this issue?
Within config.go I have:
package config


import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "os"

    "github.com/joho/godotenv"
)

func config(key string) string {
  if err := godotenv.Load("./.env"); err != nil {
    log.Fatalf("Failed to load env file: %v", err)
  }
  return os.Getenv(key)
}

This function is used, for example, to get the database connection string when setting up my DB connection.
My serverless.yml is:
service: my_service
frameworkVersion: ">=4.0.32"
useDotenv: true
provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: provided.al2
  architecture: arm64
  region: ap-southeast-1
  stage: ${opt:stage}
  environment:
    DB_STRING: ${env:DB_STRING}
    HOST_URL: ${env:URL}
    HOST_API_KEY: ${env:API_KEY}
    # Other env vars...
plugins:
  - serverless-plugin-go
  - serverless-dotenv-plugin
functions:
  api:
    handler: main.go
    events:
      - http:
          path: /healthcheck
          method: GET
package:
  patterns:
    - "!*/**"
    - bin/bootstrap



I would touch upon two points: 1) the call godotenv.Load("./.env") tries to load the file ".env" located in the process' current working directory which is a runtime property of a process and has absolutely no relation to its source code. I mean, apparently that "Serverless" thing compiles your code before running it ("stock" implementations of Go use AOT compilation) and then runs the result, and what filesystem directory ends up being current for the created process probably…

…depends on the configuration of that "Serverless" thing, or maybe it's documented someow. But I'd not expect that the CWD of the resulting process is the directory with the root of your program's source code. The second point is that you appear to fall into a common trap of newbies of trying to explicitly read ".env" files in programs which are supposed to consume environment variables from, well, their environment. This may sound strange but after making yourself accustomed with the concept it should seize to be so. …

IOW, .env files are supposed to be used by software other than your process to set up environment for your process, and your process then reads the necessary variables from its environment (using os.Getenv and similar means). The approach "read specifications of env. vars from a text file, create these vars in the environment and then read them back from there" is simply brain-dead because if you wanted a textual config, then just go ahead and use a textual config: an INI file, a YAML document, a TOML document, and XML document and so on—there are literally myriads of solutions.

It also may so happen that that "Serverless" thing is supposed to read the supplied .env file by itself. I'd check the docs.
